# nightwatch not able to select element in iFrame

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, nightwatch.js

I am trying to access an element in an iframe. I am able to switch to the frame successfully but anytime I try to check if the element is present or visible, Nightwatch says "element not found".

Here is an example of my code:

```
'User should be able to select client' : function(browser){
     var mainframe;
      browser
      .pause(15000)
      .waitForElementPresent("#cpmInteractionDivFrame", 45000)
      .element('css selector', 'cpmInteractionDivFrame', function(result){
          mainframe = result.value; 
          browser.frame(mainframe, function(result){
            browser
           .waitForElementVisible('#ClientProfileID', 35000)
          .click("#ClientProfileID")
          .waitForElementVisible('[option selected value="6032"]', 15000)  
          })         
      })
      browser.end();
    },
};
```

Is anyone else having a similar issue or know what could be causing this?

-Thanks for your feedback

Comment: When you select that iframe in the  in Chrome's javascript console (from that dropdown that says 'top') can you then find the element with $('#ClientProfileID')? Also, is the Nightwatch error on .waitForElementVisible('#ClientProfileID', 35000) or
          .click("#ClientProfileID")?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it worked for me -

```
       browser.useXpath()
       .elementIdClick(videoCard.ELEMENT)
       .frame(0) //go inside an iframe
       .waitForElementVisible("//div[contains(@class, 'html5-video-player playing-mode')]", 14000)
       .frame() // come back to main page.
       .useCss()
       .end();
```